# JQuery-File-Upload 404 Error on Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404, delete-file, jquery-file-upload

I installed JQuery-File-Upload (and Backload) using NUGET into my VS2013 MVC 4.5.1 project.

The file upload works great and I successfully uploaded 3 files.

However, when I attempt to delete any of the files, nothing appears to happen on the page and Fiddler reports a 404 error.

Moreover, all the files exist and the folder and files within them have been set to EVERYONE with full control.

Also note, the message below specifies a path for backload's handler, but, the path doesn't exist ... should it?

> C:\Projects\AustinTexasKarate\Web\Backload\UploadHandler doesn't exist.

Below are the results from Fiddler.

Note the error code: 0x80070002.

Does anyone know why delete doesn't work on my system or could provide clues? Did I miss something?

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Most likely causes:
>   •The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
>   •The URL contains a typographical error.
>   •A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
>
> Things you can try:
>   •Create the content on the Web server.
>   •Review the browser URL.
>   •Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    MapRequestHandler
>
> Handler    StaticFile
>
> Error Code    0x80070002
>
> Requested URL
>   /Backload/UploadHandler?fileName=youth_lineup.jpg&uploadContext=C:%5CProjects%5CAustinTexasKarate%5CWeb%5Cfiles%5Cphotos
>
> Physical Path
>   C:\Projects\AustinTexasKarate\Web\Backload\UploadHandler
>
> Logon Method    Anonymous
>
> Logon User    Anonymous
>
> Request Tracing Directory
>   C:\Users\Roy\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEB
>
> More Information: This error means that the file or directory does not
>   exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request
>   again.  View more information »

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Backload FAQ](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/wiki/faq#why-do-i-get-a-404-status-back-on-a-delete-request), you can tweak your Web.config to enable DELETEs without 404ing:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute">
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```