# JQuery-File-Upload Save Path & Filename

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-file-upload

I installed [Demo JQuery File Upload by blueimp with Backload MVC 4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/JQueryFileUpload_Demo_with_Backload/) on my MVC 5.1 project (VS 2013). How to get path and filename of uploading files? I want to save the path and filename in database.

Also I have a problem when delete files that have uploaded, this is already asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118035/jquery-file-upload-404-error-on-delete), but there is no response yet. I've got error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:58082/Backload/UploadHandler
```

this is not happens when I create another project on MVC 4 (VS2012). It can delete the files.
Is JQuery-File-Upload compatible with MVC 5? In release notes, said that it was developed for MVC 4. So how to implement it on MVC 5?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your exact answer. However, it may help you in correct direction.

I could not find a direct method myself. So I divided the user form in 2 parts. File upload form and other user data form. It's easy with css to make user feel its one continues form.

I upload the files first and read the file names. This is because e.g. if you upload `ten.png` and if exists in destination folder than the file-upload plugin renames it to `ten (1).png`. Hence, for me it was important to get the real file name to save in DB.

Now when, files are uploaded I get file names as follows:

```
var failed = false;
var tempfiles = new Array();
$('#fileForm').bind('fileuploaddone', function(e, data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.jqXHR.responseText);
    for (var ind in obj.files)
        tempfiles.push(obj.files[ind].name);
})
.bind('fileuploadfailed', function(e, data) {
    console.log('upload FileUpload failed !!');
    failed = true;
})
.bind('fileuploadfail', function(e, data) {
    console.log('upload FileUpload failed !!');
    failed = true;
})
.bind('fileuploadstopped', function(e) {  // called when all files finish uploading
    if (tempfiles.length == 0)
        failed = true;
    if(failed){
        // deal with failed file uploads
    }
    console.log( tempfiles ); // this should contain all file names
});
```

**Note**: if you don't care about failed file uploads, then you can safely remove the `fileuploadfail` and `fileuploadfailed` event bindings and make necessary changes.